# Whats the correct way to use HQL for data with delete flags

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, hql, soft-delete

I have several Tables which  have all a boolean field deleted.
What is the best way to filter eager loaded  collections (with hql) ie this:

```
from worker as w left join  w.taskSet as t 
where (w.deleted!=true or w.deleted is null )  
and (t.deleted!=true or t.deleted is null )
```

Wont return a worker instance if he has work which was deleted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The filtering is applied to the root entity being fetched (e.g. `Worker`) and collections won't be filtered out.

You are better off defining a [filter](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.2/manual/en-US/html/ch19.html) on both entities as well as one one-to-many associations.

Answer (score 0):

This solution worked for me

```
@FilterDef(name="NOT_DELETED")
@Filters({
    @Filter(name="NOT_DELETED", condition="not deleted or deleted is null")
})
@Entity
...
   @Column
   Boolean deleted
...
```

Usage

session.enableFilter("NOT_DELETED");